Does moving through a target by overruning them provoke an attack of opportunity?
The internet seems to have conflicting opinions about this. What is the RAW answer for this question?
If you have the improved feat for a combat maneuver, the maneuver itself doesn't provoke. (Without its improved feat, a combat maneuver normally provokes.)
Some people take this to mean that if you have improved overrun, you can move through an opponent's square without the movement provoking them.
But the feat doesn't let you move without provoking, it lets you use a combat maneuver without provoking.
Doesn't that mean you still provoke by moving through their square (leaving their threatened square), even if you have improved overrun (which lets you use the combat maneuver without provoking)?
Bonus question: If you knock someone prone by overrunning them, and they get their attack of opportunity from your movement, are they prone or are they still standing when they opportunity-attack you?

You may be interested in this question.
